# Moving a rectangle shape of a plotly dash only along y axis

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have a dash plot that has a rectangle drawn . I want the rectangle only to be moved along y axis (either up or down) no side-ways. Is there any way to do that ?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import plotly.graph_objects as go

import plotly.graph_objects as go # or plotly.express as px
fig = go.Figure()

 
# Set axes properties
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 4.5], zeroline=False)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 4.5])

# Add circles
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    xref= 'x', yref="y",
    fillcolor="PaleTurquoise",
    x0=3, y0=3, x1=4, y1=4,
    line_color="LightSeaGreen",
    
)

fig.update_layout(width=800, height=800)
#fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig,config={'editable': True,'edits': {
                                                    'shapePosition': True
                                                        } 
              })
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server( port = 8052, debug=True)
```

Can someone please answer ? or give me any ideas whether is it really possible in Dash.

Thanks,
GAP

Comment: Do you want the rectangle's width and height to remain fixed?

Comment: My actual requirement is like moving a circle like shape . I was not able to fix it with circle so created a rectangle . Also now the size of rectangle is big I want like a small size and when it is moved the height and width should remain same smaller . 

Thanks for replying !